# Silverlight DataGrid Exception Reordering Column Headers

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I'm trying to set the initial display order of the column headers in a silverlight datagrid by changing the column header DisplayIndex values. If I try to set the column order at page load time, I get an out of range exception. If I set the column order (same routine) at a later time like, in a button click handler, it works. Is this just a bug in the silverlight datagrid control? Suggestions for a possible work around?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you've got a problem modifying the DisplayIndex of the columns in the DataGrid from the Page Loaded event as they haven't yet been created at this point. You don't say but I assume you're getting the DataGrid to AutoGenerate your columns as otherwise you could just set the DisplayIndex in your XAML when defining the DataGrid columns.

When the DataGrid generates Columns it fires a AutoGeneratingColumn event for each Column allowing you to modify its properties. It's a little crude but one solution could be to set the DisplayIndex in a handler for this event using the PropertyName it is creating a column for.

```
private void grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Name":
            e.Column.DisplayIndex = 1;
            break;

        case "Age":
            e.Column.DisplayIndex = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In case anyone still cares, yes: this problem does also occur with AutoGenerateColumns == false and no, in that case you don't get any AutoGeneratingColumn event. No, the Loaded event doesn't work either. In my case, I solved by handling the LayoutUpdated event and updating display indexes only when my ItemsSource length is > 0. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

actually you need to subscribe to grid.Loaded event and reorder colums there:

```
public UserManagementControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridUsers.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(dataGridUsers_Loaded);
    }

    void dataGridUsers_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridUsers.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
    }
```

You've got ArgumentOutOfRangeException because control hadn't been loaded so far

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Automation DataGrid Control - Columns Localization and Ordering
/// Option1: Localization of Columns Automatically
/// Option2: Ordering columns in DataGrid Automatically
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dataGrid"> DataGrid control</param>
/// <param name="ContractType"> Contract of Row DataItem 
/// Example: typeof(ClientType) 
/// </param>
/// <param name="columns"> Ordered Properties of Contract
/// Example:  columns = "Id_Client,Client,GeographyItem,Flag_Approved,ClientType,ClientRelation,ClientPrestigeLevel"
/// </param>
public void AutomateDataGridColumns(DataGrid dataGrid, Type Contract, String columns)
{
    try
    {   
        List<String> OrderedColumns = columns.Split(new string[] { ",", "|", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        //Buid Order of created COLUMNS
        dataGrid.Loaded += (sndr, arg) =>
        {
            if (dataGrid.Columns.Count == OrderedColumns.Count && dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns == true)                       
            {
                foreach (var item in dataGrid.Columns)
                {
                    Int32 displayIndex = OrderedColumns.IndexOf(item.Header.ToString());
                    if (displayIndex != -1)
                    {  item.DisplayIndex = displayIndex;  }                          
                }
            };
        };

        //DataGridColumn Localization  
        dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (sndr, arg) =>
        {
                LocalizeDataGridColumn(sndr as DataGrid, arg, Contract, OrderedColumns);

                //We need To Update DataGrid  after last Column Localized -->so  Loaded event will be Raised/
                // or ArgumentOutOfRange Exception will be thrown
                if (dataGrid.Columns.Count == OrderedColumns.Count && dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns == true)
                {
                    dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
                }
        };

    }           
    catch (Exception exc)
    {  throw exc;
    }
}



/// <summary>
/// DataGridColumn Control Localization
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dataGrid">Host DataGrid control </param>
/// <param name="arg">Auto Generated Column arg </param>
/// <param name="Contract">Type Contract</param>
/// <param name="localizationColumns">Ordered Properties to Contract </param>
protected void LocalizeDataGridColumn(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs arg, Type Contract, List<String> localizationColumns)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridColumn Column = arg.Column;

        if (localizationColumns.Contains(Column.Header.ToString()))
        {
            // LOCALIZING Column.Header                      

            // Check column local resource key exist 
            // CultureKeys -  local Culture enum type 
            // SystemDispatcher - is My SL4  MEF Bootstrappper 
            // LocalizationService  - is My Localization service in SL4   
            // if somebody is interested i can share more of my LocalizationService - use mail      
            CultureKeys currntCulture = SystemDispatcher.LocalizationService.CurrentCulture;
            string ResourceKey = LocalResKeys.BoPropElmNameLoc.ToString() + "\\" + Contract.Name + @"|" + Column.Header.ToString();

            if (SystemDispatcher.LocalizationService.CultureResources[currntCulture].Item2.ContainsKey(ResourceKey))
                Column.Header = SystemDispatcher.LocalizationService.CultureResources[currntCulture].Item2[ResourceKey];                                       
        }
        else
        {    arg.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw exc;
    }

}
```